# How to retrieve query parameter in Server Script

Tags: mobile, azure

I'm using Windows Azure Mobile Service to build the backend for my app. For server script's read operation, now I want to retrieve the query parameter like $filter, $select in the script, etc. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Are you trying to invoke mobile service REST API through a desktop/Windows 8 application and trying to find out the query parameters in that application?

Comment: I don't think it matters since I'm talking about server script which is node.js in a nutshell
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554226.aspx
For read
Thing is that in the rest api documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj677199.aspx
it states there are query parameters like $filter, $select in the request, but I don't know how to retrieve those parameters. The query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hacking around with the 'query' object in the 'read' function's parameter (by using console.log ), I finally found the solution:

```
function isObject(variable) {
    return variable !== null && 
        variable !== undefined && 
        typeof variable === 'object';
}

// Find all the member-value pairs from the expression object
function findMemberValuePairsFromExpression (expr, ret) {
    if (!isObject(expr)) {
        return null;
    }
    ret = ret || {};
    for (var name in expr) {
        if (expr.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            var prop = expr[name];
            if (name === 'parent') { // Ignore parent property since it's added by us
                continue;
            }
            else if (name === 'left') { // member expression are in the left subtree
                if (isObject(prop)) {
                    prop.parent = expr; // Remember the parent
                    findMemberValuePairsFromExpression(prop, ret);
                }
            }
            else if (name === 'member') {
                // Found a member expression, find the value expression 
                // by the knowledge of the structure of the expression
                var value = expr.parent.right.value;
                ret[prop] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (expr.parent) {
        // Remove the added parent property
        delete expr.parent;
    }

    return ret;
}

// Get the filters component from query object and 
// find the member-value pairs in it
function findMemberValuePairsFromQuery (query) {
    var filters = query.getComponents().filters;
    return findMemberValuePairsFromExpression(filters);
}

function read (query, user, request) {
    request.execute();
}
```

Remember that this approach heavily relies on the inner structure of the query object so it may break in the future.

query.getComponents() also returns other parts of the query, like 'select', 'skip', 'top', etc. Basically anything of the oData protocol